# shorten lines of code repeating the same condition but with different variables

Tags: python

I got these lines of code in my script:

```
if x.name or x.number or x.address:
            if x.name and x[0] == x.name:
                result = x.name
            elif x.number and x[0] == x.number:
                result = x.number
            elif x.address and x[0] == x.address:
                result= x.address
```

This is within a function, that takes the list var `x` and checks whether those attributes `(name, number, address)` had been assigned somewhere else within the rest of the script.

In this case, `x` *can* have all three attributes assigned to it, but for when the function is called, only one of those is currently being worked on. The `x[0]` is for checking exactly which one is being called right now.

Now I don't like how I wrote this, since I'm just repeating the lines but with the other attributes.
I can't think of how to write this shorter, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original code works - this will be an equivalent:

```py
if (x[0] in [x.name, x.number, x.address]) and x[0]:
    result = x[0]
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for attr in ['name','number','address']:
    if x[attr] and x[0] == x[attr]:
        result = x[0]
        break
```

This is one easy way. If in future the attributes change you just need to change the list and it would work just fine.